# OnClickListener does not work for layout inflated in Service

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a service that has a button inflated from a layout xml file. I am trying to add an onclicklistener to the button, but for some reason the clicks are not registering correctly on the button. Here is the code for the service that inflates the layout file.

```
public class OverlayServiceLayout extends Service implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RelativeLayout mTopView;
    private Button myButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "onservicelayout creation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mTopView = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_main, null);

        windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
        myButton = (Button) mTopView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton.setText("Button's text was changed");
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //Toast.makeText(this, "on destroy was called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(mTopView != null)
        {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "button is not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try{
                windowManager.removeView(mTopView);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            mTopView = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "button is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onclickregistered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.drawable.smile);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send"));
        */
    }
}
```

Also Here is the xml layout file. It's just a relative layout with a button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="118dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="118dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What is this service supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a button to add extra functionality to the soft keyboard without having to create a custom soft keyboard. Eventually I want to make the button appear either when the soft keyboard is open or when a texting app is open. I want the button to be right above the soft keyboard and when the button is clicked it will bring up menu options. For example, you could click the button to send preset images through text. The reason why I don't want to just create a custom soft keyboard is I want the users to be able to use whatever keyboard they want while still being able to use my app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot inflate views in a service since they are never displayed on screen. If the service needs input from the user, it should start an activity which can then create UI elements with which the user can interact.

Comment: It is displaying the view correctly on the screen though. The on click listener is just not working correctly. I have another version of this where I manually create the code for the button in the service class instead of inflating a layout and everything works fine for that including the onclicklistener.

Comment: @BrandonLavigne Rather than using Toasts for debugging purposes, I suggest using `Log.d()`. Toasts can appear on top of each other so you will miss them.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should be doing that. Thanks for the tip.